# Checking an arbitrary file-content based condition with find

Tags: find

I'd like to `find` and delete all core files in some large directory tree.

To do this, I'd like to match files that satisfy a particular file name pattern, like:

```
find . -name 'core*'
```

... but once such a file is found, I also want to run the `file` command on it to make sure it's really a core dump, something like:

```
file --brief --mime <filename> | grep -q 'application/x-coredump'
```

If that command succeeds, I'd like to delete the file. Can I do it all within find?

It's important that the behavior is "shortcut": I don't want to run `file` unless the command matches the pattern, since that would be very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`find`** + **`bash`** approach:

```
find / -type f -name "*core*" -exec bash -c \
'[[ `file -bi "$0"` =~ application/x-coredump ]] && echo rm "$0"' {} \;
```

Remove `echo` call if you convinced of found "needed" filenames.

---

Or even shorter - with `find`'s *`-delete`* action:

```
 find / -type f -name "*core*" -exec bash -c \
'[[ `file -bi "$0"` =~ application/x-coredump ]]' {} \; -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible:

```
find . -name '*.core' -type f -exec \
    sh 'if file -bi "$1" | grep -qw ^application/x-coredump; then printf "%s\n" "$1"; fi' \
    sh {} \;
```

If you're happy with the result replace `printf "%s\n"` by `rm -f`.

Comment: Awesome. I'm also curious however if the check be done within `find` itself? It saves launching the shell and you can use options like `-print0` for filename handling.

Comment: @BeeOnRope - in order to avoid invoking a shell you'd have to write a program that checks the mimetype of each `core*` file found and returns success if it's `application/x-coredump` and failure otherwise; you could then run smth like `find . -name '*.core' -exec my_app {} \; -print0`

Comment: @don_crissti - so `exec` is interpreted as a predicate, per your example: so I could also use the invocation in this answer, but remove the `then printf` part and move it to `-print0`? So

Comment: @BeeOnRope - exactly, it's executed only if the previous action (`-exec blah-blah`) returned _true_. It's all in the manual...

Comment: stackexchange is my manual :)